# Update certain boxes based on checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox on my page that enables half of my input's (textboxes mostly) when checked, what I need to do in my C# is write the code that will update the first half of lines no matter what, and add the others if the checkbox is checked. I have the code I tried below but how can I efficiently accomplish this task?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string updateSQL;
        updateSQL = "UPDATE Projects SET ";
        updateSQL += "ProjectDescription=@ProjectDescription, ";
        updateSQL += "DateAssigned=@StartDate, DueDate=@DueDate, SystemNumber=@SystemNumber ";
        updateSQL += "WHERE ProjectName=@ProjectName";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectsAndTasksTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, con);

        if (CheckBox_ProjectResults.Checked == false)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", DDL1.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDescription", UpdatetxtProjectDesc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", UpdatetxtStartDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", UpdatetxtEndDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SystemNumber", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);



        }
            if (CheckBox_ProjectResults.Checked == true)
            {
                string updateSQL;
                updateSQL = "DateCompleted=@DateCompleted,TrackerNumber=@TrackerNumber, DocumentName=@DocumentName";


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCompleted", TxtActualEnd.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentName", attachmentFileUpload.FileName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackerNumber", UpdatetxtTrackerNumber.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", DDL1.SelectedItem.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDescription", UpdatetxtProjectDesc.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", UpdatetxtStartDate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", UpdatetxtEndDate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SystemNumber", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
            }


            int updated = 0;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                updated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                lblResults.Text = updated.ToString() + " record updated.";
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblResults.Text = "Error updating. ";
                lblResults.Text += err.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
    }
```

update 2

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            if (CheckBox_ProjectResults.Checked == false)
            {
string updateSQL;
            updateSQL = "UPDATE Projects SET ";
            updateSQL += "ProjectDescription=@ProjectDescription, ";
            updateSQL += "DateAssigned=@StartDate, DueDate=@DueDate, SystemNumber=@SystemNumber ";
            updateSQL += "WHERE ProjectName=@ProjectName";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectsAndTasksTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", DDL1.SelectedItem.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDescription", UpdatetxtProjectDesc.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", UpdatetxtStartDate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", UpdatetxtEndDate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SystemNumber", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);

try, catch, finally....
            }
                if (CheckBox_ProjectResults.Checked == true)
                {


                   string updateSQL;
            updateSQL = "UPDATE Projects SET ";
            updateSQL += "ProjectDescription=@ProjectDescription, ";
            updateSQL += "DateAssigned=@StartDate, DueDate=@DueDate, SystemNumber=@SystemNumber ";
            updateSQL += "WHERE ProjectName=@ProjectName";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectsAndTasksTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, con);


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCompleted", TxtActualEnd.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentName", attachmentFileUpload.FileName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackerNumber", UpdatetxtTrackerNumber.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", DDL1.SelectedItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDescription", UpdatetxtProjectDesc.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", UpdatetxtStartDate.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", UpdatetxtEndDate.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SystemNumber", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);

try, catch, finally....
                }
```

Comment: @rene do you mean changing my brackets around? I tried that and still get the same error...

Comment: the checkbox.checked shows true or false depending on if it is checked, and that works, I edited the code to what I was trying, but I was thinking maybe I need to get rid of the updateSQL or move it to something like the second update, I know it wont run but would something like that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overlooking the nested if you have created due to poor formatting:

```
if (CheckBox_ProjectResults.Checked == false)
{
// code removed
if (CheckBox_ProjectResults.Checked == true)
{
 // code removed
}
}
```

If you properly indent your code you would have easily spotted thid issues your self:

```
if (CheckBox_ProjectResults.Checked == false)
{
    // code removed
    if (CheckBox_ProjectResults.Checked == true)
    {
       // code removed
    }
}
```

One other issue that you pverlooked is the fact that string are immutatable which means they don't change value after being assigned.
After this call:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, con);
```

the `cmd` is set with the `updateSQL` string at that moment. If you a few lines down do

```
updateSQL += "...awesome sql string... ";
```

that change will not change the sql string inside `cmd` let alone it becomes magically valid sql.

Let's see what we can do to fix that. I've choosen an implementation where I keep the buildup of the sql and the parameters being added close together. I use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and want to nicely Dispose the connection so I wrapped the connection and command in an [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

```
// dispose connection
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectsAndTasksTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        // when we += multiple string we better use a StringBuilder
        StringBuilder updateSQL = new StringBuilder();
        // create our update statement 
        updateSQL.Append("UPDATE Projects SET "); // there is as space on purpose!
        // Checked is already a boolean so not much need
        // to check if this is true it either is or it isn't
        if (CheckBox_ProjectResults.Checked)
        {
            updateSQL.Append("DateCompleted=@DateCompleted,");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCompleted", TxtActualEnd.Text);

            updateSQL.Append("TrackerNumber=@TrackerNumber,");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackerNumber", UpdatetxtTrackerNumber.Text);

            updateSQL.Append("DocumentName=@DocumentName,");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentName", attachmentFileUpload.FileName);

        else 
        {
            updateSQL.Append("DateAssigned=@StartDate,");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", UpdatetxtStartDate.Text);

            updateSQL.Append("DueDate=@DueDate,")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DueDate", UpdatetxtEndDate.Text);

            updateSQL.Append("SystemNumber=@SystemNumber,");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SystemNumber", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
        }
        // this is always there so make it our last one
        updateSQL.Append("ProjectDescription=@ProjectDescription "); // notice no comma but a space!
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDescription", UpdatetxtProjectDesc.Text);

        // no matter what Projectname is always there because it is the where!
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", DDL1.SelectedItem.Text);
        updateSQL.Append("WHERE ProjectName=@ProjectName");

        cmd.Connection = con;
        // call ToString on the String builder
        cmd.CommandText = updateSQL.ToString();
        int  updated = 0;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            updated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblResults.Text = String.Format("{0} record(s) updated.", updated);
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlExc)
        {
            lblResults.Text = String.Format("Error updating. {0} - {1} - {2}"
                               , sqlExc.Message
                               , sqlExc.Number
                               , sqlExc.LineNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for the nested issue, I am still not understanding what the difference is betewwn the first two codeblock you put up, can I look up nesting in C# for more reading or should I search something else? I'll have to look up stringbuilder so I know more about it, also the else statement has an error, the final ";" before it as well. thank you for the explanation, really helped.